# I was trying this code and I got this error

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ODbRx.png)

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/utils/generic_utils.py in validate_kwargs(kwargs, allowed_kwargs, error_message)
1172   for kwarg in kwargs:
1173     if kwarg not in allowed_kwargs:
-> 1174       raise TypeError(error_message, kwarg)
1175
1176

TypeError: ('Keyword argument not understood:', 'dropout_W')

Comment: Please post code as text, not as an image. Provide a [mcve].

Comment: You probably want to check the documentation for the Keras LSTM layer: https://keras.io/api/layers/recurrent_layers/lstm/ The parameters you are using are just no there.